# jQuery html() not updating contents in corresponding id more than once in the same HTML

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a PHP view page in which I have some contents which should be displayed in some number of  pop ups. Contents are getting from database using jQuery according to values of certain drop downs. It all works fine, assuming I have contents in:

```
items ='blah blah';
```

and I'm updating this contents in span with id activity_load as:

```
$("#activity_load").html(items);
```

I have placed this span inside the contents of popup, I should have to use separate popups with the same contents so i have looped this popup, somewhat like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) { 
<div class="modal fade" id="long-modal $i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="long-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" data-border-top="multi">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="long-modal-label">Activities</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

            <span id="activity_load"></span>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close-pop" data-dismiss="modal" rel="<?php echo $i;?>">Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> }
```

By using jQuery html() I'm getting the contents only on the first popup, I thought it may because of any issues of popup but I have tried inside the HTML like adding:

```
<span id="activity_load"></span>
<span id="activity_load"></span>
<span id="activity_load"></span>
```

The contents are not showing, rather than `<span id="activity_load"></span>` use just once its working.

Comment: ID must be unique mate and will returned first matched element only even you have hundreds of element with same ID. Unless you catch it up `[id]`. Instead you class

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have multiple items with same `id`. Use `class` instead of `id`.

```
<span class="activity_load"></span>
<span class="activity_load"></span>
<span class="activity_load"></span>
```

And

```
$(".activity_load").html(items);
```

By the way, not sure if you're code is working fine because you've written `html` inside `php`. You should have following structure.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) { ?>

.. 
..
<!-- html code here -->
..
..

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Better luck next time :)

Comment: Thank you all..you just made my day.

Comment: @freelancephinix You are welcome. Please consider accepting an answer and/ort voting it up if its was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**ID's are unique**

> Each element can have only one ID
>
> Each page can have only one element with that ID

**Classes are NOT unique**

> You can use the same class on multiple elements.
>
> You can use multiple classes on the same element.

In short You can not use same id for another tag. Id is identity of certain tag and class u can use for multiple tag. for eg. for designing that tags with css

```
<span id="span1identity" class ="myspan"></span>
<span id="span2identity" class ="myspan"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a single id with classes. An id like `activity_load` can only occur once. So give it a class (`class="activity_load"`) and type:

```
$(".activity_load").html(items);
```

Comment: Thank you all..you just made my day.

Comment: @freelancephinix As mentionned in the other comment, please consider accepting and or voting an answer up when it was helpful.